# Error Send Params From Android to Webservice PHP with Ksoap2

Tags: android, ksoap2

I sent a resquest in android to webservice PHP with ksoap2 
as:

```
  String NAMESPACE="http://www.localhost:81/wsdl";
             String METHOD_NAME="insertUser";
             String SOAP_ACTIONS="http://www.localhost:81/wsdl#insertUser";
             String URL="http://10.0.2.2:81/phpWebservice/pgsql.php";
             SoapObject request=new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
             **request.addProperty("name","地獄");**       
             request.addProperty("birthday", "2012/02/01");     
             SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope=new   SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
             //envelope.dotNet=true;
             envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
             HttpTransportSE androidhttpTranport=new HttpTransportSE (URL);
androidhttpTranport.call(SOAP_ACTIONS, envelope);
```

Webservicde php as:

```
  require("nusoap.php");
  $server = new soap_server();
  $server->register('insertUser',                    // method name     
  array('name' => 'xsd:string','birthday'=>'xsd:string'),          // input parameters
  array('return' => 'xsd:int'),    // output parameters
  $namespace,                         // namespace
  $namespace . '#insertUser',                   // soapaction
  'rpc',                                    // style
  'encoded',                                // use
  'Get all user id dua vao =0'        // documentation
);  

function insertUser($name,$birthday)
{
value of $name=?? Why
}
```

value of 'name' from android is "地獄"
but webserver $name='??'
value of $name at webservice is error.
Can you help me?

Comment: this is encoding problem android side and php side use different encoding http://stackoverflow.com/questions/714713/overcome-encoding-problems-with-php-soapserver-utf-8-and-non-english-characte

Comment: i is new member php. can you support me fix this problem.

Comment: if i send param : request.addProperty("name","地獄");    how does encode to utf-8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can encode and decode

```
String encoded =URLEncoder.encode("地獄", "UTF-8"); at app            
String de= URLDecoder.decode(encoded, "UTF-8"); at server
```

( http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)