# Receiving unformatted CSV data in PHP

Tags: php, csv, soap, base64

Via an SOAP request, I am getting an object array, in one object parameter receiving "base64Binary" type of csv content. But when we are printing that csv content, it's showing corrupted data like:

`PK�|OErrorsReport_NEW.csvE�1
�@E�@�0�F��(�Q��d�/���lDocc��{�ɳ��Sf�y����w|��.����褰ȿ���v1��р����R�B��6[�v�%QC�>��4��R���YPKz��u�PK�|Oz��u�ErrorsReport_NEW.csvPKB�`

I tried to convert this data using base64_decode, unpack but didn't get readable data.

Here is the object array that I am getting:

```
 stdClass Object
(
    [UploadTransactionResult] => -2
    [errorMessage] => e-claim transaction validation is failed with errors
    [errorReport] => PK�|OErrorsReport_NEW.csvE�1
�@E�@�0�F��(�Q��d�/���lDocc��{�ɳ��Sf�y����w|��.����褰ȿ���v1��р����R�B��6[�v�%QC�>��4��R���YPKz��u�PK�|Oz��u�ErrorsReport_NEW.csvPKB�
)
```

How can I convert this to readable form?

Comment: Is this simply UTF-8  encoded data? SOAP uses XML and XML is supposed to be UTF-8 encoded

Comment: _“I tried to convert this data using base64_decode”_ - that debug output doesn’t look very base64-y to begin with.

Comment: @RiggsFolly , this looks binary data, that we need to convert i think. rest I have updated my query, I added my SoapClient connection response.

Comment: Try adding `'encoding'=>'UTF-8'` to your `$options` array

Comment: See [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/714750/2310830) making this a possible duplicate I am afraid

Comment: I tried with `'encoding'=>'UTF-8'` but getting same result.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, we have a successful request going thru and no issues reported. however, the response that we receive has a param which has CSV file in binary form. i are looking for a method to convert the binary data to a csv file. please suggest.

Comment: @This is not Duplicate question, I got the answer. Its a zip file that returning in respective parameter. I just save it as zip file and I got the respective csv file in that zip file.